# MessageBox result direct to website Vb

Tags: vb.net

Hello I wrote this code

```
MessageBox.Show(
   "Do you want contact via Facebook",
     "Help",
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
    MessageBoxIcon.Information,
   MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1)
```

But I want When they click yes, directly he go to the My facebook account in web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it, which can simply be found by doing a few Google searches.

The MessageBox returns a `DialogResult` that tells you which button you've pressed. You just have to check it in an if-statement.

```
If MessageBox.Show("Do you want contact via Facebook", "Help", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) = DialogResult.Yes Then
    Process.Start("<URL to your Facebook profile>")
End If
```

Comment: i tested . But this problem is coming   An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception' occurred in System.dll

Comment: I can do it Just I delete "<>" that symbols. it is working. THank you very much

Comment: @ÜmidMuradlı: I put the "<>" characters there to clarify it as a comment. They were ment to be removed. :)